# Why does Yarn throw "Invariant Violation: expected workspace package to exist" when I attempt to upgrade some dependencies?

Tags: yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo that is managed by [lerna](/questions/tagged/lerna) which relies on the Yarn workspaces feature. It looks like this:

```
/repo
  |-- packages
  |   |-- pkg-a
  |   |   |-- package.json
  |   |-- pkg-b
  |   |   |-- package.json
  |   |-- pkg-c
  |   |   |-- package.json
  |-- package.json
```

I use `yarn upgrade-interactive` to update a selection of dependencies across my packages but I get this error:

```
Invariant Violation: expected workspace package to exist for "@babel/plugin-transform-classes"
```

However this isn't a direct dependency of mine. When I search for it in all my `package.json` files I get nothing:

```
$ find . -name "package.json" -and -not -path "*/node_modules/*" | xargs grep "@babel/plugin-transform-classes"
$
```

It is present in my `yarn.lock` file though:

```
$ grep "@babel/plugin-transform-classes" yarn.lock
"@babel/plugin-transform-classes@^7.10.4":
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel/plugin-transform-classes/-/plugin-transform-classes-7.10.4.tgz#405136af2b3e218bc4a1926228bc917ab1a0adc7"
"@babel/plugin-transform-classes@^7.4.0":
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel/plugin-transform-classes/-/plugin-transform-classes-7.4.0.tgz#e3428d3c8a3d01f33b10c529b998ba1707043d4d"
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes" "^7.4.0"
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes" "^7.10.4"
$
```

I suspected some sort of caching issue so I tried to start from scratch inside a Docker container:

1. Delete all `node_modules` folders
2. Mount the repo in a Docker container
3. Run `yarn` to install all dependencies
4. Run `yarn upgrade-interactive`

But I get the exact same error.

I went scavenging for answers and none have fixed my issues. What strikes me the most is that nobody seems to know *why* it is happening.

Can anybody explain why it is happening and how one could reproduce this issue? Once we know why, we stand a better chance to find a proper solution.

Technical details:

- Node 12.18
- Yarn 1.22
- Lerna 3.20

Comment: What does `yarn why @babel/plugin-transform-classes` say?

Comment: @silvenon it says that one of my sub packages has a dependency that requires it. That dependency isn't in the `nohoist` config.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that it is a bug

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7734#issuecomment-580012389

And the official recommendation is to downgrade to Yarn 1.19.x or upgrade packages manually (Yarn 1 is deprecated).

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7734#issuecomment-671729912

Also, you could try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates CLI utility

Comment: This solution helped me with a project I was working on. After deleting the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling with yarn 1.19.1. The invariant violation errors are no longer preventing me from installing with `yarn add`

Answer (score 1):

Try after removing the packages from resolution section of the package.json file which you want to upgrade.